# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'evaluate'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs

How to add the code together in the useEffect? I cannot seem to find the solution.

```
const evaluate = () => {
     const [first, second] = openCards;
     enable();
     if (cards[first].type === cards[second].type) {
       setClearedCards((prev) => ({ ...prev, [cards[first].type]: true }));
       setOpenCards([]);
       return;
     }
```

To the useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
      console.log(openCards);
      let timeout = null;
      if (openCards.length === 2) {
        timeout = setTimeout(evaluate, 300);
      }
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      };
    }, [openCards]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't include it in the dependency array (second arg of `useEffect`) it won't update when evaluate changes.

```js
// use useCallback to make sure evaluate is only a new 
// closure every it's dependencies change. 
// Keep in mind `() => {} != () => {}`
const evaluated = useCallback(() => {
     const [first, second] = openCards;
     enable();
     if (cards[first].type === cards[second].type) {
       setClearedCards((prev) => ({ ...prev, [cards[first].type]: true }));
       setOpenCards([]);
       return;
     }), [openCards, cards, setClearedCards, setOpenCards])

useEffect(() => {
      console.log(openCards);
      let timeout = null;
      if (openCards.length === 2) {
        timeout = setTimeout(evaluate, 300);
      }
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      };
    }, [openCards, evalute]); // Add it here
```

Comment: The 'evaluate' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 113) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'evaluate' in its own useCallback() Hook.

Comment: It gave me that message.

Comment: @RianCoetzee closures create new objects every time they are declared. You can make it's identity stable using `useCallback`. This will only re-evaluate the closure when dependencies change. I modified my post to give an example.

Comment: @RianCoetzee if your problem is solved please accept the answer.